# How to create two instances of generic structure using different comparators?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, comparison

I am making an abstract AVL tree implementation using generics in Java. I need to have multiple instances of the tree with the same data instances but with different keys.
e.g.: Let's consider data class Car. I need it's instances to be in two trees at the same time. But the first tree will be sorted by license plate and the second by VIN number.
How to ensure that?

Comment: Please show us what your tree class looks like. It's not really clear from your question what your problem is. Objects can be stored in sorted trees using different comparators quite easily in Java.

Comment: Have you seen TreeMap for e.g. in jdk how it makes use of Comparator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your abstract tree implementation is built on top of generics, you could pass a comparator to your avl tree contructor, so you know how to keep order in your tree, according to the comparator.

```
class Tree<T> {

    private final Comparator<T> comparator;


    public Tree(final Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }
}

class Car {
    private String model;
    private String VIN;
    private String licencePlate;


    public String getModel() {
        return this.model;
    }


    public String getVIN() {
        return this.VIN;
    }


    public String getLicencePlate() {
        return this.licencePlate;
    }

}


public static void main(final String[] args) {

    Comparator<Car> comp1 = new Comparator<Car>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(final Car car1, final Car car2) {
            return car1.getVIN().compareTo(car2.getVIN());
        }
    };

    Comparator<Car> comp2 = new Comparator<Car>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(final Car car1, final Car car2) {
            return car1.getLicencePlate().compareTo(car2.getLicencePlate());
        }
    };

    Tree<Car> tree1 = new Tree<Car>(comp1); //this tree will keep order according to car's VIN
    Tree<Car> tree2 = new Tree<Car>(comp2); // this tree will keep order according to car's licence plate


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Require a comparator to be provided when creating the tree. A simpke implementation may keep a reference to it in the root node. With a factory method, something like this could work:

```
public class MyTreeNode<T> {
    private Comparator<? super T> comparator;

    protected MyTreeNode() {}

    public static <T> MyTreeNode<T> create(Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
        MyTreeNode<T> node = new MyTreeNode<T>();
        node.comparator = comparator;
        return node;
    }
}
```

Depending on how you use it, you might pass the reference on down to child nodes.